# Why is everything NOT prime?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write this program to find prime numbers. I have the basics of it down, except that no matter what number I put in, it returns as NOT prime. I've been messing with this for way too long and cannot figure out what it is. Is it in my "if" statement or my isPrime function? Please help, and thank you!

```
    var number = 0;

function main()
{
    number = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter a Number to Determine Whether or Not it is Prime:", "Enter a Number"));
    while(isNaN(number) === true)
        {   alert("You Entered an Invalid Number. Please Reenter");
        number = parseInt(prompt("Please Enter a Number to Determine Whether or Not it is Prime:", "Enter a Number"));
        }

    isPrime(number);

    if(prime = false)
        {   alert("The number " + number + " is a Prime Number!");  }
    else
        {   alert("The number " + number + " is NOT a Prime Number!"); }
}
/*------------------------------------------------------*/
function isPrime(number)
{
    if(number < 2)
        {return false;}

    var prime = false;  

    for(var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++)
    {   if(number % i == 0)
        {prime = true;}
    }

    return prime;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write `=== true`; `true` is already `true`.  Similarly, use `!`.

Comment: Let me just say that I find your brackets offensive :-/

Comment: `if(prime = false)` should be `if(prime == false)` or better `if(!prime)`. A single `=` is used for attribution.

Comment: Aside your syntax issues, I think your primality test implementation is incorrect as well. You are saying "if number is divisible by `i`, it is prime". That's basically the wrong way round.

Comment: Isn't the check for prime itself is flawed? Anything divisible by 2 is **NOT** a prime!

Comment: Also, calling `Math.sqrt()` on every iteration of the loop makes kittens cry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if(prime = false)
```

not only because you're using assignment instead of comparison, but because prime is not defined (it's not going to return/create a global variable `prime` from that function call).

Replace it with:

```
if (!isPrime(number)) {
```

Now this doesn't use a variable to store the result of the isPrime call, but uses the call directly. If you need this result in more than one place, then it would be a good idea to assign it to a variable:

```
var prime = isPrime(number);
```

and then do the rest of your code:

```
if (prime == false)...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (prime = false)
```

You just assigned `prime` to false.

You don't want to do that.

By contrast, you do want to assign it to the result of your function.

Comment: Also worth noting that the return value of `isPrime()` is being ignored anyway.

Comment: Is the scope inside the for and if different ? Because `{prime = true;}`

Comment: @DanFromGermany not sure what you mean; the variable `prime` in the `isPrime()` function is local to that function. The calling code ignores the return value.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: Really? I can clearly see `if(prime = false)`.

Comment: @DanFromGermany yea Dan that's incorrect; the scope of `prime` in that part of the code is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Oh ah you are right; I did only look at the function isPrime itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
isPrime(number);
```

leaves no variable assigned.  Therefore prime is never assigned in your test and unassigned variables are treated as false as far as boolean expressions are concerned.

It should be

```
var prime = isPrime(number);
```

You're also doing an assignment where you meant to do a comparison.

```
if(prime = false)
```

should be

```
if(prime === false)
```

Tip: If you're doing these kinds of tests, it's usually a good idea to put the thing that can't be changed by assignment on the left (function call, constant, etc).  That way if you accidentally put = instead of == or === the script will fail with an error.

```
if(false === prime)
```

If you accidentally type

```
if (false = prime)
```

you'll get

> ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

which is obvious and easy to debug.

As this is a simple boolean switch, a simple "is not true" check is fine.

```
if (!prime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually their are only 2 small logic failure.

You define "prime" inside your function isPrime() - hence you cannot use it outside your function.
You try to do if(prime = false) which assigns the value false to "prime" whick does nothing for your if except breaking it.

You need to define the variable outside hence use your `prime = isPrime()`

Also you do not need to check against "false" which by any means does not really make sense their. "true == false" ? just skip that ans ask  for if(prime) which is true or false.

Alternativly you can call your funtion directily in the if condition like:

```
if(isPrime(number)){....
```

it then automaticly checks the return value.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It looks correct to me. He's the only one to notice that merely correcting the `if` condition will cause a *ReferenceError*.

Comment: Mhm Maybe because theire are actuelly to errors in the code, i even did not notice that the author uses = to check the value, i will reflect this in an edit to also include that

Comment: Yeah, you weren't explicit about the `if` condition, but your solutions seemed to be correcting it anyway.